# How to copy and save elements from dataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I would like to ask how to copy and save selected elements from one dataGridView to another? In one dataGridView, I have elements, that can be selected, and upon selection, they are then transferred to the other dataGridView, where they will be ready for printing on paper. However, with the code below, it doesn't copy the elements correctly, as it displays ContextMenuStrip, DefaultCellStyle, DividerHeight, etc...

It also doesn't save my selection, but instead overwrites it everytime I choose new rows. How exactly do you copy and save elements (rows) from one dataGridView to another? I would like to avoid doing it with clicking, as there will be multiples of elements that need to be ready for printing.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my example, try to following this perhap?

```
if (GMDSP1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
             DataTable _dt1 = new DataTable();
             DataTable _dt2 = new DataTable();
                DataGridViewRow gvdr = GMDSP1.CurrentRow;
                DataRow[] drArr = _dt1.Select("Name= '" + gvdr.Cells["Name1"].Value.ToString() + "'");
                if (drArr.Length > 0)
                {
                    DataRow dr = _dt2.NewRow();
                    if (_dt2.Columns.Count == 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in _dt1.Columns)
                        {
                            DataColumn newDC = new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType);
                            _dt2.Columns.Add(newDC);
                        }
                    }

                    dr["ID"] = drArr[0]["ID"].ToString();
                    dr["Name"] = drArr[0]["Name"].ToString();


                        _dt2.Rows.Add(dr);
                        _dt1.Rows.Remove(drArr[0]);

                        _dt1.AcceptChanges();
                        _dt2.AcceptChanges();


                    GMDSP1.DataSource = _dt1;
                    GMDSP2.DataSource = _dt2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have decided to go for a listView instead, as it is easier to add and remove items dynamically.